# Updating data using macro

Tags: excel, vba

I want to update data recorded on a worksheet to another main copy in another worksheet. My question is how do i make it such that i can take the records on the worksheet and update as i want it? 
As of now, I can only update the last row, even if i change the row number in the code. Any idea why and how do i solve it?

The code as below

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Dim Name As String
Dim Problem As Integer


Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
Name = Range("C4")
Problem = Range("D4")
Worksheets("Sheet2").Select
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B4").Select
If Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B4").Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B4").End(xlDown).Select
End If
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Value = Name
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = Problem
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C4").Select
End Sub
```

Sheet1: Where I insert the new data and press update. This will send values to Sheet 2

[image]

Sheet 2: Data are updated here. I would like to for example, go back to the middle of this list and edit one of them, for example jo's entry.

[image]

Comment: First of all what you mean by "data recorded"? Do you mean "macro recorded"? Also, are you talking about **Worksheets** or **Workbooks** ?

Comment: No, for example, in the code, I have name and problem as variables.Now , I have the data of this 2 variables from somewhere and I want to ,using Sheet1,insert the data i have into sheet 2 where ultimately it will have a whole list of data of these 2 variables.

Comment: That is achievable, but lets say I would like to edit an old record. How can I reference to the old record and edit as I want? right now, it can only add on to the list but i can't edit. They are 2 worksheets in the same workbook. Thanks!

Comment: I think you have to post the structure of your worksheets, since to overwrite cells without figuring out how those "old records" are positioned is just guesswork :)
Besides... Your code is really full of `.Select` that don't look good

Comment: ok i will put it up. umm I am a beginner so I am not too sure what else i can do

Comment: ...what will happen if you edit `jo`? Do you want to overwrite it?

Comment: yes, 2 cases. I edit the name jo to say thomas and the number 23 to something else, say 26. Another case would be just overwriting one of them, say 23 to 26.

Comment: I understand mine macro is not dynamic enough but i am not sure how to make it as such

Comment: Question: How do you want to update name via this macro? If you insert Name: `Thomas`, how macro will know you want to edit `jo`?

Comment: Overwriting `Problem` value is easy.

Comment: I..do not have an idea. maybe userform? Actually i do not know if it can even be done. Thats why the big question mark.

Comment: oh, How do i do that? i mean overwriting Problem. That could be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I understand :)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Name As String
Dim Problem As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet, Target As Worksheet
Dim ItsAMatch As Boolean
Dim i As Integer

Set Source = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Target = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Name = Source.Range("B5")
Problem = Source.Range("C5")

Do Until IsEmpty(Target.Cells(5+i,2)) ' This will loop down through non empty cells from row 5 of column 2 
    If Target.Cells(5+i,2) = Name Then
        ItsAMatch = True 
        Target.Cells(5+i,3) = Problem ' This will overwrite your "Problem" value if the name was already in the column
        Exit Do
    End If
    i = i+1
Loop

' This will write new records if the name hasn't been already found
If ItsAMatch = False Then
    Target.Cells(5,2).End(xlDown).Offset(1,0) = Name
    Target.Cells(5,2).End(xlDown).Offset(0,1) = Problem
End If

Set Source = Nothing
Set Target = Nothing

End Sub
```

This was not tested but should work

Comment: thanks Nolder, I just tried it. it does goes to the specific name but the value changes to 0 no matter what value i have typed in

Comment: Sorry, was addressing the wrong ranges :) the correct ones are B5 and C5 for "name" and "problem". Edited my answer

Comment: yes,it does the changes now.thanks! However, a new entry will have its name and value offset from each other. the entry for Problem is at a row down compared to its name

Comment: Just curious, If my worksheets' names and the range is different from what I have today, is it possible to change other than going into the macro itself?

Comment: lol right I was stupid sorry. Edited again! The second offset should be (0,1) not (1,1). Yeah you can do what you want: you can address the worksheets by their position for instance: `Set Source = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)` and `Set Target = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)`. This way you can change their names at your will (but not their position ;) )

Comment: Please don't say that.U have helped a deal. So you do mean I would still need to go into the macro itself to change it? Is it possible to let the macro ask which 2 worksheets to compare and which range i want? Sorry if I sound like i am shooting for the sky.lol

Comment: Lol of course you could :) But that is gonna be a little trickier.
Here's my Idea: Build a UserForm which contains 2 comboboxes (which can go by the name of source and target) which by UserForm_Initialize can be filled with all the names of your worksheets. Then when you click the button to start the macro make the userform appear, select source and target and click on ok to hide it. You can get the "Source" and "Target" variables then by setting them as `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(myUserForm.Source)".
;)

Comment: It can be avoided with little messages: `If MsgBox("Do you want to copy data from " & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name & "?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then Set Source = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` if pressed `no` you can show another message with name of second worksheet. I think this approach is simpler for a beginner.

Comment: so this will go along with the useerform?

Comment: No... this is a way to avoid userform. This `If` statement will show you message with question, in your case: "Do you want to copy data from Sheet1?". All you need to do is customize what happend if Yes or No is clicked. In this example I made command to change `Source` variable to Sheet1 worksheet

Comment: Nope. He's suggesting a loop with msgboxes that ask you every time if you want them as source. Same thing with another loop with target.

Comment: Not actually a loop just nested if.

Comment: Say you have 10 worksheets... Will you nest an If with all the possibilities?

Comment: Did not think of it that way, you are right. In that scenario loop is required and probably Useform is simpler.

Comment: So userform would be better? well anyway I still thank you both for the help.its really great!

Comment: If you have to write some code, you'd better leave possibilities open, so you don't have to re-write it... So yeah, a UserForm would be better IMHO